# Calculation of the stock price

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis

Is the stock price calculated using the midpoint of the bid ask spread like how it is for crypto's or is it actually the the latest price is which bid and ask orders were matched?

Comment: It depends on your purpose. If you want to know what you can buy it for, use the ask. If you want to know what you can sell it for, use the bid.  If your doing historical analysis, any of those are fine as long as you're consistent.